# Display and Upload files MS access with SQL Server backend

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

I'm responsible for an internal ticketing system used to initiate work for our team. I've finished converting the MS Access database into SQL Server 2008 R2 but I'm hung up on the attachment functionality that was previously handled in Access.

Does anyone have any code samples that display a list of files (from SQL Server) where user can click and view? The user should be able to upload new attachments to the `varbinary(max)` column.

Thanks!

Paul

Comment: Could you save the actually files somewhere on the file system and just save the path and filename in SQL Server?

Comment: I would prefer not as our future plan is to move out of access and into PHP.  Ideally we would like to keep all the data in the database.  Thanks for the suggestion @nscheaffer

Comment: Are these files all the same data type? You want to retrieve the filename from the varbinary field - without extracting it first? I don't think that's possible - you'll probably need a second field to show the list of files. To retrieve the binary data I think you should be able to use ADO and the Stream object

Comment: These will be different file types .doc .xls .jpg.  I'm pretty novice to access so I'm looking for an example if one exists on how to do this.